# Replace relative image url to absolute from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, preg-replace

Hello I am getting article from database like this (joomla)

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT id, title, introtext, `fulltext` FROM #__content WHERE catid = 33 AND state = 1 ORDER BY ordering asc, id desc");
$json->data = $db->loadObjectList();
```

so `$json->data` contains information like this:

```
<p>example parahraph </p><img src="/images/example.jpg"><p>example paragraph</p><h1>example heading</h1>
```

I want to find images (src="") in text and replace /images/example.jpg to http://example.com/images/example.jpg

Comment: `how to use preg_replace or something like this?` - By simply applying the right regex rules to it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: hello, I am new in php I found code where I can replace relative urls to absolute but not src="" this code:    $data->introtext = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#", '$1'. $absolute_url .'/$2$3', $news->introtext);

Comment: $json->data contacints other information also, texts, links etc.. I want to found only image and replace to absolute path from relative